# not able to bind property in spring form

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-form

I have class User and userRole, I need to bind UserRole object in User 
i tried below code

**UserRole.java**

```
public class UserRoleBean {
private Integer role_id;
private String roleName;
private String roleDesc;
//getter setter
}
```

**User.java**

```
public class UserBean {


private Integer userId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Date dob;
private String emailAddr;
private String mobileNo;
private Integer balance;
private String password;

private UserRoleBean roleBean;
//getter and setter;
```

}

**AddUser.jsp**

```
<form:form method="POST" action="saveUser.html" modelAttribute="userBean">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="userId">User ID:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="userId" value="${user.userId}" readonly="true"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="firstName" value="${user.firstName}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name :</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="lastName" value="${user.lastName}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="emailAddr">Email Address :</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="emailAddr" value="${user.emailAddr}" readonly="false"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td><form:label path="dob">Date Of Birth:</form:label></td>
                 <td><form:input path="dob" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="mobileNo">Mobile No :</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="mobileNo" value="${user.mobileNo}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="password">Password:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:password path="password" value="${user.password}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="balance">Balance:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="balance" value="${user.balance}"/></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><form:label path="roleBean">Select Role:</form:label></td>
               <td>
            <form:select path="roleBean">
            <form:option value="0" label="Select" />
            <form:options items="${forRoles}" itemValue="role_id" itemLabel="roleName" />
            </form:select> 
                </td>

            </tr> 
       <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="${cap}"/></td>
    </tr>
        </table> 
    </form:form>
```

Other Property is bind but roleBean unable to bind, how to do this,
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try binding using the path with `role` instead of `roleBean` in `<form:select path="roleBean">`.

Comment: You shouldn't use the entity clases in the gui

Comment: no change problem is still same,  rolebean is return null

Comment: Change path="roleBean" to path="roleBean.roleName". You have to tell which property of roleBean you want to set value too.

Comment: role_id property i wanted to bind with roleBean, but it try with roleBean.role_id

Comment: You have to set each property of roleBean seperately like you were doing for User object. While setting any property of roleBean use roleBean.role_id for Id.

Comment: thanks its working, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set each property of `roleBean` seperately like you were doing for User object.

While setting any property of `roleBean` use `roleBean.role_id` for `Id`, `roleBean.roleName' for 'roleName'.

Like your path for `roleName` is `<form:select path="roleBean">` but it should be `<form:select path="roleBean.roleName">` if its for `roleName`. Same goes for other attributes.

Comment: I am displaying roleName and store the role_id, now it's working fine, thank you so much for your help and consideration

Comment: Thank you @DhavalJoshi. Happy to help.